# CSS ID's issue. Unable to style

Tags: css, html

I am stuck in a problem. I am learning HTML CSS these days and I am practicing a basic layout.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Karan-Mehul\Desktop\asssi.css" />
<title>Assignment 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
         <h1> My First Website </h1>

    </header>
    <p>Welcome to my website! Here are a few things I enjoy Favourite Quotes Here is another favourite quote of mine Favourite Quotes Here is another favourite quote of mine And another And another</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Web Dev</li>
        <li>Chess</li>
        <li>Reading</li>
        <li>Learning</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
        <li>Web Dev</li>
        <li>Chess</li>
        <li>Reading</li>
        <li>Learning</li>
    </ol>
    <div id="try">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever ly with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <footer>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever ly with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
p {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 330px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    line-height: 37px;
}
ul {
    background-color: green;
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
header {
    text-align: center;
}
ol {
    background-color: brown;
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px;
}
#try {
    background-color: #005157;
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}
footer {
    width: 700px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

My problem is that I am not able to style anything in `div id="try"` and `<footer>`

Why is that happening? And why I am getting red color by default? I haven't specified any styling. Moreover the wrapper is styled as background-color:blue so even if the color had to come it should be blue, no?

Comment: Have you tried to use browser's dev tools (usually F12) and see what styles are set on each element where thy are coming from?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ezeyed/1/

Answer (score 0):

### The issue

You've come across something that trips up people very frequently, whenever you float an element, it no longer effects the parent element in terms of adding to it's height.

That's why only your title area has the blue background, since the h1 is not floated, so it's height DOES contribute to the main wrappers height, but the floated elements do not.

### The fix

There's a few approaches for fixing this, but there's one that's become pretty much a standard fix. It is know as the clearfix, you can read up more here: http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/

Basically, you need to add the following to your CSS:

```
/* new clearfix */
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Then, in your wrapper, and try sections, add class="clearfix" to make sure that any elements inside them that are floated, still attribute to the wrapping elements height, e.g.,

```
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
```

Side note... you haven't closed the `<div id="wrapper">` tag

Comment: When you find helpful solutions, you should upvote them or mark as the answer, so when other people see this question they can know which answers are correct

Comment: answer some q's and get yourself some cred! :)